# How to resolve the memory leak issue, when a custom control is placed into the Collection view data template

Tags: xamarin.forms, memory-leaks, xamarin.android, custom-controls, collectionview

I designed a custom control that will contain content and will be primarily used to display a basic animation before loading the content. We used **ValueAnimator** to start and stop the animation in our custom control. When we placed the custom control inside the **Collection view** data template, we encountered a memory leak on the Xamarin forms **Android** platform. We used a garbage collector and added a destructor method to the content page to check for memory leaks. When we investigated the problem, we discovered that it only occurs when the custom control is placed within the collection view. We used the update event in the value animator to refresh the view, as shown in the code below.

```
`public void AddWaveAnimator()
        {
            if (animator == null)
            {
                animator = ValueAnimator.OfFloat(0, 1);
                animator.RepeatCount = ValueAnimator.Infinite;
                animator.SetInterpolator(new Views.Animations.LinearInterpolator());
                animator.Update += OnWaveAnimatorUpdate;
            }
            else
            {
                animator.End();
            }
            animator.SetDuration((int)(1000d));
            animator.Start();
        }
private void OnWaveAnimatorUpdate(object sender, ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
        }
`
```

Surprisingly, the issue does not occur when the animator update event is commented out. When invoking the update event, the memory leak happens. I'm not sure if it's a framework issue or not because the problem only happens when the custom control is placed inside the collection view. Is there anyone who knows how to address this problem? Please get the sample from the below link.
[Click here to download Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3Brl3ZAGPQrUifEO2F-ZE5WOROshaos/view?usp=sharing)

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. In the custom control page, we have a destructor method to check whether the memory is correctly disposed or not.
2. Keep a break point in the destructor method and run the sample.
3. When navigating back and forth to the custom control page the destructor method will not be raised
4. If we remove the below line
   animator.Update += OnWaveAnimatorUpdate;

The destructor method is called correctly.

#### Expected Behavior

The destructor method should be called when navigating back and forth to the custom control page

#### Actual Behavior

When navigating back and forth to the custom control page the destructor method will not be raised

Comment: After downloading your code ,we found there are only a simple `CustomViewClass`  in the second page. How can we produce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT, i have added the replication steps in the description

Comment: `Keep a break point in the destructor method and run the sample.`  Sorry, I didn't find the `destructor ` method .